# eclipse not showing all of the methods declared in a file

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am always getting an error "method or field is undefined for the type xxx". But, it is defined in the file.

The Outline view also do not show this method. It does not show at least half of the methods declared in the file.

If do the Open Declaration for this method, eclipse cannot find it, even if it is declared in the file. The same also happened for all the methods that are not displayed in the Outline View.

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this?